# box-api Download a File: how to save raw text response to file with correct encoding

Tags: box-api

I implemented downloading a file. I received raw string data. I save this data to a file, but can't open it, because file is invalid.

I tried to download jpg image.
I think this is a result of incorrect converting this data to bytes.

What Encoding I need to use?

Comment: What tool/language are you using to try and download the file?

Comment: Yes, can you provide any sample code? We can't really help much without that.